# Permutations and Combinations( Miscellaneous)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many distinguishable ways can the symbols a,a,a,b,c,d,e,f be permuted in groups of 4?

Comment: What do you mean by "permuted in groups of 4"?

Comment: That's how is the question asked.

Comment: I expect that this is either lost in translation, or the question author is bastardizing the words being used.  I expect that what you truly mean to ask is how many sequences of length four can be created using characters from $\{a,a,a,b,c,d,e,f\}$, noting that no character can be used more than once with the exception of $a$ which can be used up to three times and the different $a$'s are otherwise considered identical.

Comment: Ok. If that's the case, what is the solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Setup:**

Break into cases based on the number of $a$'s being used.

If exactly $n$ copies of $a$ are used in the string, pick which locations in the sequence they occupy in $\binom{4}{n}$ ways.  Then, from left to right, pick which character occupies each remaining space.

For example, if exactly two $a$'s are used, pick where they go in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.  Then pick the left-most non-$a$ character in the string in $5$ ways (*as there are five non-$a$ characters available to choose from*) and then pick the remaining character in $4$ ways (*as after picking the earlier character it is no longer available, leaving only $4$ left to choose from*).  This gives a total of $\binom{4}{2}\cdot 5\cdot 4$ different ways where exactly two $a$'s were used.

Sum over all possible values of $n$ to get the final count.

Comment: A downvote?  Just because I'm not willing to give the OP a final numerical answer without forcing them to put in some effort to try to understand?  Surely, its not because my answer is incorrect or doesn't lead to an easy to understand solution...